# I am getting an ambiguous reference error even though I am using fully qualified name

Tags: c#, visual-studio, razor

I have a `cshtml` file that references a class called `SessionHelper`, but two projects in the solution have a class called `SessionHelper`.

So I am using the fully qualified name when referencing it but still getting an error. Here is the code:

```
var type = RPracticeSite.Controllers.Helpers.SessionHelper.ProductType;
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: What are the namespaces for both `SessionHelper` classes?

Comment: What's the errer?

Comment: It's perfectly possible for multiple assemblies to contain types with identical fully-qualified names. It's perfectly possible that this is the case here.

Answer (score 1):

You have the same cs file included in two different projects, whose assemblies are loaded in the same process.